# Access bookmarks from Safari Extension?

Tags: html, safari, bookmarks

Is it possible to access Safari's bookmarks from a Safari Extension? I'm currently trying to develop an extension that should display a second bookmark bar in Safari. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Noone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible for security reasons. If an extension could access your bookmarks, even read-only, a malicious extension could potentially publish undesirable information about your browsing habits surreptitiously to all sorts of places.

Comment: A malicious extension could track everything you do on every website you visit anyway, so security reasons cannot really be the issue here. Probably Apple just doesn't want anyone to mess with their users' bookmarks in possibly confusing ways. Too bad :(

Comment: Wait, then how can users expect a Safari add-on for bookmarking purposes, like the many available in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: You can do it, just not using the extension API. Unfortunately, Apple doesn't publish the other APIs that you have to use instead, so such apps (such as Xmarks) tend to break with major OS updates.